# Column mismatch in excel

Tags: excel, vi

I have huge set of data in my excel sheet. If you see the image, you can see for example , all the email ids do not fall in the same column. I have no clue  how to arrange it in a proper manner other than doing it manually. I tried using filters. I am not able to apply filters for more than one column. Or is there any other better way to do this operations like Vi editor or something?
[image: My Excel sheet]

Comment: Do you think it's responsible to post a screenshot of data including people's personal information?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formatting in Microsoft Excel.

Comment: It is publicly available data scraped from a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e 's:":"Q:g' -e \
's/\(Designation\|Name of the industry\|Specification\|Date of admission\):/" ,&," /g' \
-e 's:"Q:what you want to replace phony " with:g' \
-e 's:"[, ]:":g' -e 's:^:":' -e 's:$:":'
```

(I assumed that the separator in excel sheel is the comma , and used the nonexisting strings inspired of https://stackoverflow.com/a/20002782/2987828)