# script to replace all dots in a file with a space but dots used in numbers should not be replaced

Tags: unix, scripting, replace, awk, vi

How to replace all dots in a file with a space but dots in numbers such as `1.23232` or `4.23232` should not be replaced.

for example

Input:

```
abc.hello is with cdf.why with 1.9343 and 3.3232 points. What will
```

Output:

```
abc_hello is with cdf_why with 1.9343 and 3.3232 point_ what will
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat file
abc.hello is with cdf.why with 1.9343 and 3.3232 points. What will
this is 1.234.
here it is ...1.234... a number
.that was a number.

$ sed -e 's/a/aA/g' -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\)\.\([[:digit:]]\)/\1aB\2/g' -e 's/\./_/g' -e 's/aB/./g' -e 's/aA/a/g' file
abc_hello is with cdf_why with 1.9343 and 3.3232 points_ What will
this is 1.234_
here it is ___1.234___ a number
_that was a number_
```

Try any solution you're considering with that input file as it includes some edge cases (there may be more I haven't included in that file too).

The solution is basically to temporarily convert periods within numbers to some string that cannot exist anywhere else in the file so we can then convert any other periods to underscores and then undo that first temporary conversion.

So first we create a string that can't exist in the file by converting all `a`s to the string `aA` which means that the string `aB` cannot exist in the file. Then convert all `.`s within numbers to `aB`s, then all remaining `.`s to `_`s then unwind the temporary conversions so `aB`s return to `.`s and `aA`s returns to `a`s:

```
sed -e 's/a/aA/g'                                     #    a ->   aA  encode #1
    -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\)\.\([[:digit:]]\)/\1aB\2/g'  #  2.4 -> 2aB4  encode #2
    -e 's/\./_/g'                                     #    . ->    _   convert
    -e 's/aB/./g'                                     # 2aB4 ->  2.4  decode #2
    -e 's/aA/a/g'                                     #   aA ->    a  decode #1
    file
```

That approach of creating a temporary string that you KNOW can't exist in the file is a common alternative to picking a control character or trying to come up with some string you THINK is highly unlikely to exist in the file when you temporarily need a string that doesn't exist in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that will do what you want:

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]\)\.\([^0-9]\)/\1_\2/g' filename
```

This will replace all dots that are not between two digits with an underscore (`_`) sign (you can exchange the underscore with a space character in the above command to get spaces in the output).

If you want to write the changes back into the file, use `sed -i`.

Edit:

To cover dots at the beginning resp. end of the line or directly before or after a number the expression becomes a bit more ugly:

```
sed -r 's/(^|[^0-9])\.([^0-9]|$)/\1_\2/g;s/(^|[^0-9])\.([0-9])/\1_\2/g;s/([0-9])\.([^0-9]|$)/\1_\2/g'
```

resp.:

```
sed 's/\(^\|[^0-9]\)\.\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1_\2/g;s/\(^\|[^0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\)/\1_\2/g;s/\([0-9]\)\.\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1_\2/g'
```

Comment: That won't handle a period at the start or end of the line or before or after a number.

Comment: Updated solution won't handle contiguous sequences of periods.

Comment: @EdMorton: OK - I have to admit - you found a special case which I cannot cover with my approach.

Comment: I don't think finding a sequence of periods in text is all that special (`I wonder.... could it be special?`), it's just another typical edge case. The "special" (by which i assume you mean unlikely) one I think is probably periods at the start of lines, but you get that in mis-typed sentences and who knows what the OP is dealing with... (oops, there they are again.).

Answer (score 0):

[gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk)

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '!/^[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+$/{gsub("\\.", "_")}; {printf "%s", $0RT}' file.txt
```

Comment: wont handle periods at the start of lines or after numbers

Comment: @EdMorton, i think i fixed it with the edit, but then again, i like your solution better, +1.

Comment: Thanks. Your updated version is closer but will wrongly convert periods within numbers if there's no white space between the number and other text, try it with the input file I posted and note what happens to the numbers on the 2nd and 3rd lines of input.

Answer (score 0):

since you tagged with `vi`, I guess you may have `vim` too? it would be a very easy task for vim:

```
:%s/\D\zs\.\ze\D/_/g
```

Comment: That fails for periods at the start and end of lines, contiguous chains of periods, and possibly other cases. Try it on the input file I posted in my answer.